# Navbar is not displayed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why there is no `navbar` in the below `snippet`? Am I **missing** something? If yes, What?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <center><button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want like the below image:
[image: have a look at this image]

**Color is changed**!

Comment: there one `print button in navbar`

Comment: be more specific what you want to know.. You have given on button in navbar and it is displaying though

Comment: @Bhargav But, why there is no line like https://imgur.com/a/QxBYR

Comment: @AravindReddy please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172345/navbar-is-not-displayed#comment81294202_47172345

Comment: which kind of link @AkshayMandale

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: so see my answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `.navbar-default`, adding it will show the navbar.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <center><button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Update

Also for your information, `<center>` tag has been deprecated referring to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

You could use `text-align: center` or in your case since you are using bootstrap if you want the same effect as `<center>` you could add the class `.text-center` to parent element.

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap, a navigation bar can extend or collapse, depending on the screen size.

A standard navigation bar is created with `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <center><button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```